# How do I get latest value for Cubism Metrics

Tags: javascript, cube, cubism.js

I'm trying to log the latest data from a metric (actually in reality to update a div) but the dummy code below only ever logs out "undefined".

```
var context, cube, metric;
context = cubism.context().step("1e4").size(1080);
cube = context.cube(CUBE_SERVER);

metric = cube.metric("median(sar(value).eq(key,'ldavg_15').eq(host,'myserver'))");

metric.on("change", function(start, stop) {
  console.log("changing");
  if (typeof this.valueAt !== "undefined") {
    console.log(this, this.valueAt(-1));
  }
});
```

Can anyone show me some working code for the *valueAt* function? The same metric does work by the way as it is used elsewhere to plot a horizon graph.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid `this` in `on` handler refers to something else.

Use `metric.valueAt(<your index>)` instead, which will be 1079 (the last index of the metric data array, 1080 is the size of it).